# Dynamic function call in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, dynamic-function

I have multiple functions:

```
fun testadd(payload) = 
({
addition: payload.value1 as Number + payload.value2 as Number
})

fun testsub(payload) = 
({
substraction: payload.value1 as Number - payload.value2 as Number
})

fun testmultiply(payload) = 
({
multiplication: payload.value1 as Number * payload.value2 as Number
})
```

I want to call the function dynamically based on the value of **"Operation"** property/element.
suppose **if "Operation" = "testadd"** then call **testadd** function,
**if "Operation" = "testsub"** then call **testsub** function

**Input :**

```
{
"value1" : 10,
"value2" : 20,
"Operation" : "testadd"
}
```

Comment: The parenthesis around the body of the functions are redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative here is to use function overloading and [literal types](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dataweave-type-system#literal-types). For example:

```
%dw 2.0
output json

fun binOp(a, b, op : "add") = a + b
fun binOp(a, b, op : "sub") = a - b
fun binOp(a, b, op : "mul") = a * b
---
binOp(10, 20, "add")
```

DataWeave will call the correct function based on the value of the `op` parameter.

Comment: Note that this method requires to modify the function signature to add the literal type.

Answer (score 4):

Since functions in DataWeave are named [lambdas](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-functions-lambdas#assign-a-lambda-to-a-var) you can could just convert them to lambdas, assign them as values of an object and use the keys as the names.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var functions={
    testadd: (payload) -> {
        addition: payload.value1 as Number + payload.value2 as Number
    },
    testsub: (payload) -> {
        substraction: payload.value1 as Number - payload.value2 as Number
    }
}
---
functions[payload.Operation](payload)
```

Output (for the input in the question):

```json
{
  "addition": 30
}
```

Alternatively you could have the functions as functions and just reference them by name in the object:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun testadd(payload) = {
    addition: payload.value1 as Number + payload.value2 as Number
}

fun testsub(payload) = {
    substraction: payload.value1 as Number - payload.value2 as Number
}

var functions={
    testadd: testadd,
    testsub: testsub
}
---
functions[payload.Operation](payload)
```